# PTIJ: Halachos of illegal immigrants/aliens

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Based on the consequences of alien *fires* (unsanctioned strange fires which weren't given permission) that Nadav and Avihu brought (Parshas Shemini, [Leviticus 10:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.10.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0)), what is the Torah's perspective on illegal immigration (illegal aliens)? And would this exclude a Ger Toshav?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Seriously, though: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105573/what-would-qualify-a-sedomite-as-a-righteous-person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what type of "alien" or "foreigner" the person is. There are two types of "foreigners" mentioned in the Torah.

One is called a זר, loosely translated as "stranger" or outsider. These people are absolutely forbidden to even approach any Israelite as it says in Bemidbar 18:4:

> וְזָ֖ר לֹא־יִקְרַ֥ב אֲלֵיכֶֽם׃
>
> A stranger shall not come near to you

The second type of foreigner is called a גר. Regarding these people, the Torah says:

> תּוֹרָ֣ה אַחַ֔ת יִהְיֶ֖ה לָֽאֶזְרָ֑ח וְלַגֵּ֖ר הַגָּ֥ר בְּתוֹכְכֶֽם׃
>
> There shall be one law for the citizen and for the stranger who dwells
> among you.

So if someone is a גֵּ֖ר, we see not only is he allowed to live with Israelites, but, he has the same laws as them.

There are numerous *halachot* regarding what classifies a person as a גר vs. a זר that are beyond the scope of my explaining it, here. You'd have to ask a גר Hassid about the details.